# WebSphere Application Server v855 displaytable 1.2 empty list

Tags: websphere-8, displaytag

We have recenlty migrate to WebSphere Application Server V8 but we have an error when we have many user on the displaytag (V1.2) library. DisplayTable doesn't take in input the list pass by jsp few times. Problem seems to be random but occurs only with many user. We do an remote debug and see that data are available in jsp but no way to know why DisplayTable doesn't take every time the list in the "PageContext". have you got an idea of the problem ?

Session issue aren't be able because from remote debug we see data in session of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems comes from the settings of the files web-ibm-ext.xml. We had the following attribute :

When the following setting is set, your tag lib must following an pattern in the end of the tag.

By default value is desactivate.